# Turning on a Wifi Enabled Light switch using java?

Tags: java, sockets, wifi

I have a Wifi enabled plug socket that is able to be turned on or off using my iPhone. I was wondering whether there is a way to do this in Java (Programatically)? If so, would it require a API?

Wifi Socket type and model:

MECO WiFi Plug Socket Smart Remote Control Socket

Item model number: MECOOiowied3775

What have I done so far?

Tried connecting to it using a Java socket

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    LightsOn();
    }

    public static void LightsOn() throws IOException
    {

        DataOutputStream printStream;



            Socket aSocket = new Socket("192.168.1.111", 8080);


            printStream = new DataOutputStream(aSocket.getOutputStream());

            printStream.write(0);
            printStream.close();



    }
```

Any help, advice or resources would be most welcome?

Comment: We can't really help you unless you include the model of the WiFi socket.

Comment: It's better to edit your question and add information like that into it.

Comment: I cannot find any official user documentation about this device, but from what I have been able to gather, it runs its own WiFi endpoint that mobile devices have to connect to, and then use a Broadlink mobile app to control. Broadlink utilizes the [QUIC UDP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QUIC) for its communications. Here is a [breakdown of what Broadlink's QUIC commands look like](https://blog.ipsumdomus.com/broadlink-smart-home-devices-complete-protocol-hack-bc0b4b397af1). And it looks like there might be some 3rd party Broadlink API implementations floating around.

Comment: In which case, the code you have will not work, since it is trying to connect to a TCP server, not using UDP over a particular WiFi network.

Comment: Thank you so much, this will be a great help!